# Converting powers to number of applications of a (lambda) function

Tags: python, lambda

This question is about implementing a mathematical formula in Python (using NumPy and SciPy packages).

Let *L1* and *L2* be two mathematical operators (which generally do not commute, that is: *L1(L2(x)) =/= L2(L1(x))* ), assume I have the following formula: apply *(L1 + L2)^n* on *x*. For example: if *n=2* then:

> (L1+L2)^2 x = (L1*L1 + L1*L2 + L2*L1 + L2*L2 )(x) =
>   L1(L1(x)) + L1(L2(x)) + L2(L1(x)) + L2(L2(x))

How do I treat powers (positive integers) of an operator as the number of application of it on the input?
I think this is may be done using Python's lambda functions but I am not sure how.

Comment: For small *n* I can compute the formula explicitly and easily program it. The challenge is to do so automatically for large and even general *n*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the specific problem of computing (L1+L2)^n x I found a solution, using recursion.

```
def f(L1,L2,x,n) :
   if n == 0 :
       return x
   else :
     return L1( f(L1,L2,x,n-1) ) + L2( f(L1,L2,x,n-1) )
```

One can also write it as a loop, progressing from n=0 to the desired power.